# How to cast from text to int if column contain both int and NULL values in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting, null

As in title. I have one column which has some text values. For example column data1 has values ('31',32','',NULL). Now I want to update another column say data2 (type INT) with data from data1, so I am trying to do something like that:

```
UPDATE table SET data2=CAST(data1 AS INT).
```

The problem is because PostgreSQL cannot cast NULL or empty values to INT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, you can cast `NULL` to int, you just can't cast an empty string to int. Assuming you want NULL in the new column if `data1` contains an empty string or NULL, you can do something like this:

```
UPDATE table SET data2 = cast(nullif(data1, '') AS int);
```

If you want some other logic, you can use for example (empty string converts to -1):

```
UPDATE table SET data2 = CASE WHEN data1 = '' THEN -1 ELSE cast(data1 AS int) END;
```