# How can I query for a substring whose value is >= 60000

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, pattern-matching, amazon-redshift

I have a dataset with a data that is formatted like this:

```
Date        | exec_time
------------+---------
Today       | 99999 ms
Yesterday   | 1 ms
Tomorrow    | 50000 ms
Another Day | None Recorded
Last Day |  ms
```

What I need to do is write a query to get all of the `exec_time` values that are `>= 60000`

The way I've tried to write it is like this:

```sql
select exec_time 
from myTable
where exec_time not like '%N%'
and cast(split_part(exec_time,' ', 1) as int) >= 60000
order by len(exec_time) desc, exec_time desc
limit 10
```

However, when I run this, I get this error:

```
ERROR: Invalid digit, Value '2', Pos 0, Type: Integer 
  Detail: 
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Invalid digit, Value '2', Pos 0, Type: Integer 
  code:      1207
  context:   
  query:     2780081
  location:  :0
  process:   query0_61 [pid=0]
  -----------------------------------------------
```

Any ideas how I can get around this?

Comment: I think the problem may be the `None Recorded` value. [Have a look at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626346/how-to-cast-from-text-to-int-if-column-contain-both-int-and-null-values-in-postg), it may help you with your problem.

Comment: I changed `len()` to `length()` and, using version `9.3.1`, it worked. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5fcd5/2

Comment: Can you change the schema and data to be more sensible? The `exec_time` should probably be a number in milliseconds and you should use `NULL` for that "none recorded".

Comment: It does work in the sqlfiddle, but on my machine (against the full data set) I still get the invalid digit, Value '2'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error: `WHERE` conditions are not executed in any given order.
Use a `CASE` statement to avoid the exception.

```
SELECT exec_time 
FROM   myTable
WHERE  CASE WHEN exec_time NOT LIKE '%N%' THEN
         split_part(exec_time,' ', 1)::int >= 60000
       ELSE FALSE END
ORDER  BY length(exec_time) desc, exec_time desc
LIMIT  10;
```

While being at it, if `'None Recorded'` is the only case to rule out, use a faster left-anchored check:

```
exec_time NOT LIKE 'N%'
```

If the above still errors out, check with this to find any offending rows you may have missed:

```
SELECT DISTINCT exec_time
FROM   myTable
WHERE  exec_time NOT LIKE '%N%'
AND    exec_time !~ '^\\d+ '  -- not all digits before the first space
```

In modern Postgres you only need a single backslash. `'^\d+ '`! Seems you have to double up on backslashes in Redshift, which seems to still use the outdated [Posix escape syntax for strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-varchar-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729) by default, and without explicit declaration (`E'^\\d+ '`)!

Generally, it's not a good idea to mix data this way. You should have an `integer` column to store execution time. Much cheaper, cleaner and faster.

Comment: @johncorser: I added a bit to debug this.

Comment: The debug code yielded thousands of results, all of them look something like `52 ms` but with different numbers. Why is `exec_time !~ '^\d+ '` not taking care of those?

Comment: @johncorser: This makes no sense ([fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/3978)) - unless we are dealing with different kinds of white space, like tab characters ... check for `\t` in a regexp match or leading white space.

Comment: Or maybe Redshift is still using the outdated [Posix escape syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-varchar-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729) for strings by default. Redshift is a weird mix of very old code and new additions. It's certainly not Postgres. Updated my check.

Comment: `ERROR: type "e" does not exist` Looks like that wasn't it

Comment: Ah- I found it by removing that E. there is also a data point that looks like this ` ms`.

Comment: @johncorser: I added an explanation for that.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the "None Recorded" value.  I don't know if it is going to run the first where to exclude the first or not.  Try this:

```
SELECT exec_time
FROM (SELECT exec_time FROM myTable WHERE exec_time NOT LIKE 'N%') as foo
WHERE cast(split_part(foo.exec_time, ' ', 1) as int) >= 60000
ORDER by length(foo.exec_time) desc, foo.exec_time desc
limit 10
```

Comment: Interesting, it seems to work for me on my postgresql.  What version of postgresql are you using?

Comment: @Joe: Your answer *should* work fine. I suspect a problem with whitespace characters not being spaces or leading white space ...